# Multiple tcs34725 color sensors on arduino uno

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-uno

So i'm trying to connect multiple tcs34725 sensors to an arduino using https://github.com/Fire7/Adafruit_TCS34725_SoftI2C and https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_TCS34725. With one sensor and connecting to analog works but not with digital

I tried using the Adafruit_TCS34725_SoftI2C library to emulate I2C on digital pins but i keep not finding the sensor. I#m using the example code from that library.

If i'm trying to do something impossible, how would i connect multiple to one I2C?

Comment: You will probably get more targeted help here: [arduino.se]

Comment: A few basic concepts to understand: 1) I2C is a bus, it allows multiple devices to be connected on the same bus with _different_ I2C address. 2) But for TCS34725 chip, it only has _one_ I2C address, so it can't connect more than one to the same I2C bus. In order to connect multiple TCS34725, you need a I2C multiplexer such as [TCA9548A](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2717) which allows 8 I2C devices to be multiplexed.

Comment: But isnt there a software solution using the library i mentioned? That's what i was trying to do, because i couldnt connect both to the same bus